# Expand Cell at selectedIndex

Tags: swift, firebase, tableview, row, cell

**Updated Code Below**

I am working on comment cells who are limited to 100 characters and if they contain more a "show more button" will show up.

If pressed, the exact cell should reload itself with the number of lines changed to 0 and fully display the cell, no matter how big.

What I have achieved is that cells reload, but not the selected one and kinda arbitrary.

Below is my code for the enlarging process

**NOTE: Updatet Code for My Function**

*Problem: I have to press the button twice to get the result, to minimize and to maximize the cell*

```
   @IBAction func readMore(_ sender: UIButton) {


    self.state = !self.state

    print("state" , state)
    self.tapMore.setTitle(self.state ? self.decreaseState: self.expandState, for: .normal)
    self.commentLabel.numberOfLines = (self.state ? self.expandedLines: self.numberOfLines)
    print(self.commentLabel.numberOfLines)
    let myIndexPath = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        self.parentViewControllerCommentCell?.tableView.reloadRows(at: [myIndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation(rawValue: Int(UITableViewAutomaticDimension))!)
    })
}
```

The index comes from

```
extension CommentTableViewCell {

var indexPath: IndexPath? {
    return (superview as? UITableView)?.indexPath(for: self)
   }
}
```

**Note**

The print statement prints out the chosen cell ( e.g. [0, 1] or [0,0] but it doesn't change then.

Whereas I hardcode my code and change
    let myIndexPath = IndexPath(row: indexPath!.row, section: 0)

to 
    let myIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)

The feature works, but arbitrarily reloads some cells and arbitrarily enlarges and decreases the cell.

In the variable version with row: indexPath!.row the lines state doesn't change as well, whereas with hardcoded the lines change between 3 and 0.

Thanks for your help :)

**Addition**

my commentCell

```
class CommentTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var likeCountButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var profileImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var commentLabel: KILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var likeImageView: UIImageView!


@IBOutlet weak var tapMore: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var tapMoreButton: UIButton!


var delegate: CommentTableViewCellDelegate?
var postId : String!
```

Comment: which version of Swift you are using? Your button is in tableview cell?

Comment: swift 4 and the button is in the CommentTableViewCell

Comment: @Fangming Ning answer is the right approach.

Comment: @SaqibOmer, can you please help me with the following? I have to press the button twice to enlarge and twice to minimize, why is it this way with the code above?

Comment: Posted answer mate. Accept if it works :)

Comment: Hi, my func works, but likle i said i have to click it twice, would be nice to tell why it appears to be this way:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a better approach to get you the correct index path. First, in your `cellForRow` method, add the current index row as tag to your show more button, and then add click action to your button handler function.

Add an outlet of `UIButton` in you custom `UITableViewCell` class as

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
     @IBOutlet var moreButton: UIButton! // Connect your button from storyboard
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell") as! CustomCell
    cell.moreButton.tag = indexPath.row
    /* Just add action normally from storyboard. No need to add target. cell.moreButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(buttonUp(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside) */

    return cell
}
```

Then in your handler function, you can get the correct index path by reading this tag

```
func tapForMore(sender: UIButton) {
    let myIndexPath = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
    print("myindex", myIndexPath)
    //... other code here
}
```

Comment: so the function has to be in the TableView instead of the cell?

Comment: @Zash__ What I'm doing is to add a function listener to each button in your cell so that in the listener function, you know which button is clicked. In my case my function is not *in* the `TableView`. It's just a normal function.

Comment: @Zash__ look at my code, you are adding target to the button of your cell, not the cell itself

Comment: @SaqibOmer You cannot directly connect a button. The button is in a table view cell and it connect to the custom `UITableViewCell` class, not here as an `IBOutlet`

Comment: @Fangming Ning: yes correct, the button has to be connected to the cell instead of the vc as each cell created has the button available

Comment: @FangmingNing Button is in tableview cell. There is nothing wrong in connecting button this way.

Comment: Okay now I get the proper tag of the cell but my code still doesn't work. It keeps on reloading cell with tag 1 no matter what cell I click on :D Moreover the state doesn't get changed and the lines do not change from 3 to 0 to let it expand fully. The change of the Text also does only appear if I click it double instead of changing each time

Comment: @Zash__ You mean, you create the indexPath as row 2 and do the refresh on that indexPath, it's refreshing another cell?

Comment: @FangmingNing : When I press on the more button at the first comment it prints out "my index [0,0] and now finally refreshes the pressed cell. But still does not do the line with :         self.commentLabel.numberOfLines = (self.state ? self.expandedLines: self.numberOfLines)
Even though its supposed to change, it stays at 3 and always prints out "numberOfLines : 3", whereas in the hardcoded version it changed the state and number of lines accordingly

Comment: @Zash__ Are you saying that `commentLabel` is from the table cell? There are way smarter way to access that label instead of storing it as a property in your view controller

Comment: the commentLabel is linked in the CommentCell, I will add it in my initial post

Comment: Well thanks in advance because now it working, but not properly, I have to press the button 2 times to change the size and 2 times to decrease again in size, the rest is working as I wished thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You take class variable and track tap counts. Depending on these variables you can increase or decrease size of cell and reload it.

In YOURViewController declare variables as:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

       @IBOutlet weak var CommentsTableView: UITableView!
       var defaultSizeOfCell = 60.0
       var newSize = 80.0
       var selectedIndex = -1

       var isExpanded = false
       var expandCounter = 0
       override func viewDidLoad() { ...
```

Connect button in cell to this action:

```
@IBAction func moreButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if !isExpanded {
        if expandCounter == 0 {
            expandCounter = expandCounter + 1
        } else if expandCounter == 1 {
            expandCounter = 0
            isExpanded = true
            selectedIndex = sender.tag
            let myIndexPath = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                self.CommentsTableView.reloadRows(at: [myIndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation(rawValue: Int(UITableViewAutomaticDimension))!)
            })
            print("Increase")
        }
    } else if isExpanded {
        if expandCounter == 0 {
            expandCounter = expandCounter + 1
        } else if expandCounter == 1 {
            expandCounter = 0
            isExpanded = false
            selectedIndex = -1
            let myIndexPath = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                self.CommentsTableView.reloadRows(at: [myIndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation(rawValue: Int(UITableViewAutomaticDimension))!)
            })
            print("Decrease")
        }
    }


}
```

In tableview datasource function add tag to button:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "testCell", for: indexPath) as! TestTableViewCell
    cell.moreButton.tag = indexPath.row
    return cell
}
```

And finally add this delegate method for height of cells:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if selectedIndex == indexPath.row {
        return CGFloat(newSize)
    } else {

        return CGFloat(defaultSizeOfCell)

    }

}
```

Not to mention, button should be in cell and connected to YOURCustomTableViewCell class as:

```
class TestTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

      @IBOutlet weak var moreButton: UIButton!
```

I have tested it against your requirements.

Comment: Hey I still have the problem that I have to press the button twice to change its state